# MySQL - Ordering IN within INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a system that allows a user to search a database of photo albums images for a keyword, it's working great, the only issue is that I'm ordering relevancy by the amount of times that keyword appears in an album. I'm doing this using:

```
SELECT collections_ids.collection_id
 FROM `keywords`
 INNER JOIN collections_ids ON keywords.id = collections_ids.photo_id
 WHERE keywords.`keyword` = 'trees'
 GROUP BY collection_id
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

As said, this works great.

The only issue is, when this is included in an "WHERE IN" query, it loses it's order and is returned randomly. For clarity, here is the query:

```
SELECT collections.id,
       collections.title
       images.img_small
FROM `collections`
INNER JOIN images ON images.id = collections.cover_photo
WHERE collections.`id` IN
    (SELECT collections_ids.collection_id
     FROM `keywords`
     INNER JOIN collections_ids ON keywords.id = collections_ids.photo_id
     WHERE keywords.`keyword` = 'trees'
     GROUP BY collection_id
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

I've tried researching, and people have suggested using the FIELD function, but I don't see that working in this context.

Any suggestions?

Comment: on which column of order by do you need to main query ?

Comment: You would need to add the select for the count(*) as a column in your main select, and then do a order by on it.

Comment: Does a collection have many images?

Comment: Outer query doesn't have `order by` clause, so, result from outer query will be randomly returned. Also  `order by` in subquery, not necessary at all in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sub query as join and take it count(*) as order by like below

```
SELECT collections.id,
               collections.title
               images.img_small
        FROM `collections`
        INNER JOIN images ON images.id = collections.cover_photo
        INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT distinct collections_ids.collection_id As collection_id,COUNT(*) as total
             FROM `keywords`
             INNER JOIN collections_ids ON keywords.id = collections_ids.photo_id
             WHERE keywords.`keyword` = 'trees'
             GROUP BY collection_id
             ) as A
    ON A.collection_id =collections.collection_id
    order by A.total
```

Comment: You don't need `ORDER BY` in the subquery.